# Python pandas dataframe populate hierarchical levels from parent child

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

I have the following dataframe which contains Parent child relation:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'Parent':['a','a','b','c','c','f','q','z','k'],
                      Child':['b','c','d','f','g','h','k','q','w']})
a
├── b
│   └── d
└── c
    ├── f
    │   └── h
    └── g
z
└── q
    └── k
        └── w
```

I would like to get a new dataframe which contains e.g. all children of parent `a`:

| child | level1 | level2 | level x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d | a | b | - |
| b | a | - | - |
| c | a | - | - |
| f | a | c | - |
| h | a | c | f |
| g | a | c | - |

I do not know how many levels there are upfront therefore I have used 'level x'.

I guess I somehow need a recursive pattern iterate over the dataframe.

Comment: based off of the line of code you posted with the dictionaries for the dataframe, how is one supposed to know that `'d'` is a child of `'b'`? I see it in your diagram, but how does the data you have or that is being input showing that relationship?

ah, nvm I see it now - the first parent is the parent of the first child, the second parent is the parent of the second child, etc. so d is the fourth child, and so is the child of the fourth parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest

- building each `children:parentList`
- build the `DataFrame` with giving each parent a `level` name

```
import pandas as pd

values = {'Parent': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'f', 'q', 'z', 'k'],
          'Child': ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'k', 'q', 'w']}

relations = dict(zip(values['Child'], values['Parent']))

def get_parent_list(element):
    parent = relations.get(element)
    return get_parent_list(parent) + [parent] if parent else []

all_relations = {
    children: {f'level_{idx}': value for idx, value in enumerate(get_parent_list(children))}
    for children in set(values['Child'])
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_relations, orient='index')
print(df)


  level_0 level_1 level_2
b       a     NaN     NaN
f       a       c     NaN
d       a       b     NaN
g       a       c     NaN
h       a       c       f
q       z     NaN     NaN
k       z       q     NaN
w       z       q       k
c       a     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: I'm a little confuse with this line:  children: {f'level_{idx}': value for idx, value in enumerate(get_parent_list(children))}, I know is list comprehension but how it's possible to pass children to get_parent_list when it's being defined in the same line?

Comment: @juanjoseperezhernandez "same line" is the purpose of dict/list comprehension (2d dict comprehension here), the `children` is defined in `for children in set(values['Child'])` . If it were a classic loop you'd have that line then the line using it